# How to get parent object in multi-level object array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and each object has the same keys.

```
export const MENUS = [
    {
        "type": "main",
        "submenu": [],
        "path": "/a"
    },
    {
        "type": "main",
        "submenu": [
            {
                "type": "submenu",
                "submenu": [
                    {
                        "type": "submenu",
                        "submenu": [],
                        "path": "/b/4"
                    },
                ],
                "path": null
            },
            {
                "type": "submenu",
                "submenu": [],
                "path": "/b/1"
            }
        ],
        "path": null
    },
    {
        "type": "main",
        "submenu": [],
        "path": "/c"
    }
]
```

Now, I have a key and value (path: '/b/1') and I want to fetch parent object by key/value in array.

this is the result what I am looking for when I use { path: '/b/1' }.

```
{
        "type": "main",
        "submenu": [
            {
                "type": "submenu",
                "submenu": [
                    {
                        "type": "submenu",
                        "submenu": [],
                        "path": "/b/4"
                    },
                ],
                "path": null
            },
            {
                "type": "submenu",
                "submenu": [],
                "path": "/b/1"
            }
        ],
        "path": null
    },
```

If I use {path: '/c'}, then the result will be a root array. (equal to MENU)
If anyone has a good solution, please advise me.
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried so far.

Comment: thanks for your reply, @Sean. I've just changed something. please let me know if it's clear.

Comment: Also note: this is not a multidimensional array. It's an array of objects.

Comment: Your edit did not add what you've tried so far.

Comment: oh. I am sorry. I changed the object data what I want to get.

Comment: Please take a look at it again.

Comment: Your edit still did not add what you've tried so far. What code have you written to try to solve this problem yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getObj(array, key, value) {
  return array.find(item => isThisItem(item))
  function isThisItem(current) {
    const entries = Object.entries(current)
    for (const [k, v] of entries) {
      if (k === key && v === value) return true
      if (Array.isArray(v)) {
        for (const f of v) {
          if (isThisItem(f)) return true
        }
      }
      if (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null) {
        if (isThisItem(v)) return true
      }
    }
  }
}

// usage
const obj = getObj(MENUS, 'path', '/b/1')
```

Comment: Good answers include some explanation—not just code.

Comment: Awesome!. It is what I am looking for.